# Custom Angular Lint Rule

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, eslint, angular14

I want to add a lint rule in the angular application. The lint rule will give me a warning/error that anybody should not call the function inside a tag.

```
<span>call()</span> // will give error/warning in html
```

Comment: This code will render the following text: `"call()"`. It will **not** call the function `call()`. So I don't understand why there is a need for a lint rule.

Comment: @JSONDerulo no this will not shown as string. In angular you can call funtions in a interpolation but it's bad practice because of performance issues

Comment: @DerHerrGammler the code in the question was edited. At the time when I commented, my statement was true.

Comment: Oh ok then sry. I didn't saw that

Answer (score 0):

According to my researching, I would say this is impossible.

If u just want lint the html file, take a look at these libraries: [HTMLHint](https://htmlhint.com/docs/user-guide/list-rules) and [HTML Eslint](https://yeonjuan.github.io/html-eslint/docs/getting-started/)

But none of them could check function call.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but a reason could be that the question is clearly about Angular, and there is a ESLint plugin for Angular which actually has a rule like this.

Answer (score 0):

This rule already exists. Add `angular-eslint` to your projekt and use the `@angular-eslint/template/no-call-expression` rule.

Here you can find the package: https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint

Answer (score -2):

Typescript does type checking, and is by no means a code structure validator. Simply put, you can't achieve this with TS and will have to write your own function.